# what is wrong with datatable ajax url

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

i have problem with datatable server side.

My table index url adress is the address.com/customers/edit/39. First time i got data from address.com/customers/datatable/39, but then i filtering - datatable request url is address.com/customers/edit/39. I using:

```
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/media/js/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js

```
// Data tables
$('#customers-list-data').dataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: '/customers/datatable/39',
    columns: [
        { data: 'first_name', name: 'first_name' },
        { data: 'last_name', name: 'last_name' },
        { data: 'phone', name: 'phone' },
        { data: 'country', name: 'country' },
        { data: 'city', name: 'city' },
        { data: 'address', name: 'address' },
        { data: 'email', name: 'email' },
        { data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
    ],
pagingType : 'full_numbers',
    dom: '<"dt-top-row"Bfl>r<"dt-wrapper"t><"dt-row dt-bottom-row"<"row"<"col-sm-6"i><"col-sm-6 text-right"p>>>',
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'collection',
            text: 'Save <span class="caret" />',
            buttons : ['csvFlash', 'excelFlash', 'pdfFlash']
        },
        'colvis'
    ]
}).columnFilter({
    sPlaceHolder: "head:after",
    aoColumns: [
        { type: "text" },
        { type: "text" },
        { type: "text" },
        { type: "text" },
        { type: "text" },
        { type: "text" },
        { type: "text" },
        null
    ]
});
```

first time on reload page Request URL:http://address.com/customers/datatable/39?draw=1

after filtering on input Request URL:http://address.com/customers/edit/39?draw=2 (my browser url http://address.com/customers/edit/39)

columnFilter.js do not exactly request correct url

Comment: I'd love to help but i really cannot understand what you're asking, can you maybe formulate this clearer?

Comment: And so what is the question ?

Comment: Why ajax request  url after filtering is ajax: '/customers/edit/39'?

Comment: If you've hard-coded the Id `39` into the url, then datatables will _always_ use that url when making any call to the server.  Is it supposed to be a variable?

Comment: yes, this is harcoded, but is not general thing. the main problem is that on filtering where datatable request is not ajax: '/customers/datatable/39', but browser url /customers/edit/39

Comment: you must use **?** for id parameter like _ajax: '/customers/datatable?39'_
or you should mention property **url** of ajax call